# Battery gets discharged down to 80% while the MacBook Pro is plugged in and the power adapter is the power source

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

The **Optimized Battery Charging** setting is turned on.

When the charge is high, say, greater than 80%, at some point, the following appears under the **Battery** icon on the menu bar:
Power Source: Power Adapter 
Charging on Hold (Rarely Used on Battery)

When the above happens and the MacBook is still plugged in,

Expected (assumed) behavior:
The charge percentage does not change. The Mac consumes power through the power adapter and not the battery.

What is happening:
The charge percentage discharges down to 80 still while still showing that the power source is the power adapter. The adapter is cold to touch so clearly it is not being used to power the Mac. See attached picture. The discharge on the left is happening while the corresponding battery menu bar is shown on the right.

[image]

OS is Sonoma 14.1.1.

Comment: I think it's expected that a value higher than 80% will reduce to 80% when optimizing is occurring.